# JSF h:outputStylesheet converter - dynamic css?

Tags: java, css, jsf-2

I just noticed `<h:outputStylesheet/>` has a converter attribute. After attaching a dummy (pass-through) converter to it, nothing happened. On closer inspection, it seems the converter isn't even called despite hitting the browser refresh button.

Is this attribute good for anything? Is it just there as a side effect of various design decisions?

The reason I ask is that it would be nice to perform some client- or server-side css processing with [less](http://lesscss.org/) or similar and I thought this attribute might help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *Is this attribute good for anything? Is it just there as a side effect of various design decisions?*

That's indeed "by design" since the component extends [`UIOutput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIOutput.html). It does indeed not use the converter for anything.

---

> *The reason I ask is that it would be nice to perform some client- or server-side css processing with less or similar and I thought this attribute might help.*

You can just use EL the usual way in CSS resources loaded by `<h:outputStylesheet>`. This was initially implemented in order to resolve background image resources properly.

```css
.some {
    background-image: url(#{resource[images/some.png]});
}
```

The above example assumes the image to be in `/resources/images/some.png`. If you're using a library, you need to prefix the resource name with `libraryname:`.

```css
.some {
    background-image: url(#{resource[somelibrary:images/some.png]});
}
```

Which assumes the image to be in `/resources/somelibrary/images/some.png`.

But other than that, you could basically use EL in the CSS resource for anything else. E.g. dynamically resolving colors, fonts and so on.

```css
.some {
    color: #{theme.color};
    font: #{theme.font};
}
```

Where `#{theme}` can be a session or maybe application scoped managed bean.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. I'm pursuing the option of using [less](http://lesscss.org/) because I'm not entirely comfortable with separating variables (e.g. dimensions) from CSS. (There are some nasty issues around less expecting the css to be inserted before the script.) However, your idea of themes provides a more structured and acceptable way of doing that. Server-side performance isn't an issue because JSF is already parsing the CSS. The other advantage of EL is that I continue to enjoy NetBeans's CSS syntax highlighting and autocomplete.

Comment: Looks like this strategy is a no-go. It requires a redeploy for virtually every change, even with JRebel whose purported "CDI changes" support is limited to changes to the bodies of existing methods in existing beans. If you have any tips to get around this, I'm all ears.

Comment: Redeploy for which change? In the CSS file, you mean? Even a Ctrl+F5 in browser doesn't help? Try upgrading to latest JRebel. If in vain, post at Zeroturnaround.com forum. Their support is excellent.

Comment: Redeploy for bean change. JRebel's CDI support - at least in GlassFish - is quite minimal. New beans aren't detected; I can live with that. New methods are not detected either, which is a pain. Every time I want to define a new property in the `theme` bean, I need to redeploy to pick it up. JRebel support isn't that fantastic when it comes to GlassFish unfortunately. This issue was brought up over 6 months ago and nothing ever became of it. You'd think that GlassFish, being the reference implementation, would enjoy the best support not the worst.

Comment: Dealing with Zeroturnaround and making progress. No need for me to add any more comments here now.

Comment: Ah well. I've different experiences. JRebel is fantastic in Tomcat/JBossAS with JSF managed beans. I haven't used it before in Glassfish with CDI managed beans. Glassfish has already by itself pretty decent hotreload support, right?

Comment: I tested GlassFish hot reload via NetBeans deploy-on-save yesterday because I was getting frustrated with my JRebel misadventures. I was very impressed when I saved a class and it redeployed in under a second. Then I was disappointed when, on numerous occasions and at the drop of a hat, GlassFish would throw a hissy fit (lots of exceptions) after saving something in NetBeans and the whole project would get undeployed. This required a full redeploy to get it back. Errors aside, the difference between this and JRebel is JRebel hot-reloads lazily whereas NB+GF deploy-on-save hot-reloads eagerly.

Comment: Ah well. I don't use Netbeans. Sorry, I can't tell anything constructively from experience as to that IDE.